# App Created with ios4 is crashing in ios6 and not installing

Tags: iphone, ios4, crash, ios6

My App, which is created for iOS4, is crashing in iOS6 and is not installing on simulator or  device.
It just shows the splash screen and crashes.
Did finish Launching is not being called.
Can anybody please Help?

Comment: are you using both applicationDidFinishLaunching and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, In that case applicationDidFinishLaunching will not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the solution of my problem mentioned above.
In my ios4 App, in FirstViewController.xib "Use AutoLayout" was checked.
I just removed the checkmark and my App start working.
Amazing!!!

Comment: Finally got solution great !!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a new project, and either carefully looking for the changes in delegate or any deprecated code, or just moving all of your code to the new project.  Also, you should run a convert to modern syntax check.

Comment: I have a very large application so this is not a suitable way that create new App,so please suggest another good solution.

Comment: I am not saying create a whole new app, create a blank project and compare the pieces you are having trouble with to the equivalent of the fresh project.  For example, your app delegate.

Comment: i Have checked every thing is same in AppDelegate.m and info.plist file too.

Comment: I had similar problems with updating from iOS 4 to 5, and that kind of checking really helped.  That and a trip to WWDC I was lucky enough to win.  So I'm afraid I cannot offer any more advice other than to check everything, refactor to ARC and new syntax, and consider importing all of your old code into a fresh project.

Answer (score 0):

There may be issue with Application Delegate. The obvious reason - your object is not set as an application delegate.

Looking at Apple documentation there is quite a few ways to accomplish it:

> Remove application delegate binding in Interface Builder (.xib file
>   for the window) Set 4th parameter of UIApplicationMain in main.h to
>   something else than nil.

Check you nib file in Interface Builder and see if the App Delegate is setup.

Or Reference to documentation [Core Application Design](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html)

Hope this will you out.

Comment: I replaced 
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); 
with 
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); in main.m file but still crashing..:(

Comment: When i was facing issue, here it was missing delegate in XIB file only. May be i can fix issue after look in to code/ or snap shot.

Comment: I dont have MainWindow.xib ,i created it in my app delegate programatically through
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
should i remove this???

Comment: Check if you self.navController; not nil and make its property type Retain/ Strong. hope this will fix your issue

Comment: Problem is that the AppDidFininshLunching is not being called thats why i am not able to find where is crash.

Comment: are you using both applicationDidFinishLaunching and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, In that case applicationDidFinishLaunching will not called. This is last try that i can do without look into code. :)

Comment: Sorry,yes i am using only didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and its not being called.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the **release notes** of xcode, ios6 
It is said that when working with IOS6, Auto Layout is turned on and that crashes the app if used on older versions. Check the link, which has other things to watch out for:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html